# DeadlineExceededError despite using ndb.put_multi_async

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have the following POST method in my api. After sending a big JSON collection around 350 entries to the api, I get an DeadlineExceedError exception.

I already am utilising the `ndb.multi_put_async`.  I don't know what else I could do to speed this up?

```
def post(self):
        arguments = self.reqparser.parse_args()
        json_records = arguments.get('records')
        user = User.query(User.email == request.authorization.username).get()
        if user:
            records_put_list = []
            events_put_list = []
            for json_record in json_records:
                record_id = json_record['record_id']
                rec = Record.get_or_insert(record_id,
                                           user=user.key,
                                           record_date=record_date,
                                           timestamp=record_timestamp)
                for json_event in json_record['events']:
                    event = Event.get_or_insert(json_event['event_id'],
                                                parent=rec.key,
                                                user=user.key,
                                                is_deleted=json_event['is_deleted'])
                    if event.timestamp < json_event['timestamp']:
                        event.user = user.key
                        event.record = rec.key
                        event.date_time = event_dt
                        event.timestamp = json_event['timestamp']
                        event.parent = rec.key
                        events_put_list.append(event)
            ndb.put_multi_async(records_put_list)
            ndb.put_multi_async(events_put_list)
            return '', 201
        else:
            return '', 401
```

This is the exception. Any advice what I could do?

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle
        result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~feeltracker1/1-0-1-0.376950929493492366/lib/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~feeltracker1/1-0-1-0.376950929493492366/lib/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~feeltracker1/1-0-1-0.376950929493492366/lib/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~feeltracker1/1-0-1-0.376950929493492366/lib/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~feeltracker1/1-0-1-0.376950929493492366/lib/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 397, in wrapper
        resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~feeltracker1/1-0-1-0.376950929493492366/lib/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
        return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~feeltracker1/1-0-1-0.376950929493492366/lib/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 487, in dispatch_request
        resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~feeltracker1/1-0-1-0.376950929493492366/application/http_basic_auth.py", line 36, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~feeltracker1/1-0-1-0.376950929493492366/application/rest_api_view.py", line 362, in post
        is_deleted=json_event['is_deleted'])
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3401, in _get_or_insert
        return cls._get_or_insert_async(*args, **kwds).get_result()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result
        self.check_success()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 320, in check_success
        self.wait()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 304, in wait
        if not ev.run1():
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py", line 235, in run1
        delay = self.run0()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py", line 197, in run0
        callback(*args, **kwds)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 474, in _on_future_completion
        self._help_tasklet_along(ns, ds_conn, gen, val)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 371, in _help_tasklet_along
        value = gen.send(val)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 1015, in transaction
        ok = yield tconn.async_commit(options)
    DeadlineExceededError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Task API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push) to split this processing job into smaller batches (e.g. 100 entries per task - you can find the optimum number).

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the right logic. Do not put the get_or_insert in the loop - that is never going to work for anything except the smallest number of records (and is generally an anti-pattern to avoid). Instead create the entities and append them to the list inside the loop. Once this is done, the put_multi will then take this list and handle all the puts in parallel. There is a question about how many items in a put_multi list is tolerable, but 350 is far from what I remember as a limit.

Comment: But I need to update the entries if they already exist, hence I need the `get_or_insert`. If I always was going to create them, then your approach would have made sense. agreed?

Comment: I would do a combination of what @stevep is saying with Andrei's answer about the taskqueue. You certainly want this to happen in the background.

Ideally you'd use tasklets to handle your 'get_or_insert' equation, and do as much of this work in parallel that way as possible.